# Invalid arguments

Tags: c#, xna, arguments

i am expanding on the XNA game studio 2D tutorial and adding menus from the microsoft XNA Game studio website. i thought it would be just plug in and run, but is much more complicated than i thought. here is one error, i will post more as i get them.
Here is the debug window:

> C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\GameStateManagementSample - Copy\GameStateManagement\Screens\GameplayScreen.cs(81,24): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDeviceManager(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game)' has some invalid arguments
>   C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\GameStateManagementSample - Copy\GameStateManagement\Screens\GameplayScreen.cs(81,50): error CS1503: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'GameStateManagement.GameplayScreen' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game'
>
> Compile complete -- 2 errors, 0 warnings
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

And here is the code:

```
public GameplayScreen()

        {
            //new GraphicsDeviceManager(this) has the error line under it!!!
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
```

Comment: i don't understand ... what code do i put in

Comment: public class GameplayScreen : GameScreen
then this code won't work i get another error.
public class Game : IDisposable

Comment: i get an error when i use 
public class Game : IDisposable

Comment: ok so i did this now
    error line under Gameplayscreen
public GameplayScreen()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(IDisposable);
            content.RootDirectory = "Content";
      error CS1520: Method must have a return type

Comment: Are you following the walk-through link I included below?

Comment: i skimmed the page see anything about menus maybe i overlooked it.

Comment: Don't skim, follow the walkthrough.  This ain't rocket science, but simple copy & paste isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the constructor for `GraphicsDeviceManager` a valid [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.aspx) object instead of the current class using `this`

Also, a walkthrough that may be helpful to create [your first game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're working on the `GameStateManagmentSample`. If so, since the graphics device is already available in `ScreenManager` so the only thing you need to do is call the graphics device instead of define a new graphic.

```
ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
```